# How to filter a list based on matching values and populate with arrayformula

Tags: google-sheets, filter, array-formulas

Hoping someone can please help shed some light on the below for me...

I have two tabs ('FIRST' and 'SECOND') in Google Sheets with the following columns.

FIRST:

- 'User'
- 'Contact 1'
- 'Contact 2'
- 'Contact 3'

SECOND:

- 'User'
- 'Contact email'

I want to be able to use an arrayformula which automatically populates Contact 1, 2, 3 etc based on every 'Contact email' a user has in SECOND, i.e. by looking up 'User' in FIRST in SECOND.

I've tried to use a formula like this in FIRST:

```
={arrayformula(transpose(FILTER(SECOND!B2:B10,A2:A10=SECOND!A2:A10)))}
```

However:

1. this just returns all the values. I think I'm possibly using FILTER's condition incorrectly?
2. it does not auto-populate the rows below it

Any assistance would be greatly appeciated :)

Example sheet:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1m0IZYt1l_9iWiKasmZDOUdxRD6nCdvOyq6aMAgZ9hl8/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Please read how to and [share a test sheet](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/138383/117311) so as you can be easier helped.

Comment: share a copy / sample of your sheet with an example of the desired output

Comment: I agree with the above two contributors. Formulas are written around specifics, and as of right now, we have none. Keep in mind also that if there are any variations in "User" name for the same user (even a single additional space added where it doesn't belong), you'll have trouble; or rather, a formula will need to account for such variations.

Comment: Apologies @marikamitsos and all - I've now updated the question with an example sheet.

Answer (score 0):

### Solution

> In FIRST Sheet cell `B2` paste this formula and drad side ways

```
=ArrayFormula(IF($A$2:$A="",,IF(B$1="",,VLOOKUP($A$2:$A,SECOND!$A$2:$Y,MATCH(B$1,SECOND!$1:$1,0),0))))
```

[image]

**Note:** I changed the user format to make it clear to follow along. [**Sheet Link**](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/17hktU5XLf6QmHQJwSEWwu9TydGJGX7Y4I9OWPtn2OCY/edit?usp=sharing)
In SECOND Sheet

[image]

In FIRST Sheet i added a drop down to validate user and avoid mistakes
take a look at [Create an in-cell dropdown list](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/186103?hl=en&co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop)

[image]

Comment: Thanks @Osm - to clarify, the second tab should only have 2 columns, i.e. 'User' and 'Contact email'. This means the user will appear in multiple rows, one for every contact they have (as per the original example sheet). Is it possible to please modify your suggestion based on that? I appreciate the input :)

Comment: yes its possible just delet it, if you want another form of info for example address you can do it easily by typing in SECOND sheet address _"i feel you'll need it next"_, anyways i updated the [Sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/17hktU5XLf6QmHQJwSEWwu9TydGJGX7Y4I9OWPtn2OCY/edit?usp=sharing) take a [look](https://i.imgur.com/h2ZZ0ZV.png).